# Is VS picking the wrong specialisation? Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++17

Here's some code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

namespace detail
{
    std::string Foo(const double val)
    {
        return std::to_string(val);
    }
}

using Value = std::variant<std::monostate, double, int, bool, std::string>;
struct ReadStore {};

struct ValueException : std::runtime_error {};

using PrintConvType = std::function<Value(const Value&, ReadStore&)>;


template <typename InType, typename OutType, typename CallableType, CallableType Callable, bool Strict>
Value ConvWrapperImpl(const Value& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<InType, Value>)
    {
        return Callable(value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (value.index() != 0)
        {
            const auto* ptr = std::get_if<InType>(&value);
            if (ptr)
                return Callable(*ptr);
        }

        return value;
    }
}


template <typename T1, typename T2, T2 (*Callable)(const T1&), bool Strict = false>
Value ConvWrapper(const Value& value, ReadStore&)
{
    return ConvWrapperImpl<T1, T2, decltype(Callable), Callable, Strict>(value);
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, T2 (*Callable)(T1), bool Strict = false>
Value ConvWrapper(const Value& value, ReadStore&)
{
    return ConvWrapperImpl<T1, T2, decltype(Callable), Callable, Strict>(value);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace detail;

    ReadStore store;
    PrintConvType func = ConvWrapper<double, std::string, Foo>;

    Value result = func(3.14159, store);
     std::cout << std::get<std::string>(result) << '\n';
}
```

It's a contrived MCVE, but the general idea in the original project is to provide a shorthand for wrapping the conversion of `Value` to the appropriate argument type for some callback function, and for wrapping the conversion of said function's return type back to `Value` again.

This is fine [under GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aca704385c0f0831) and Clang, but my Visual Studio 2017 (v15.7.2) errors out:

```
error C2440: 'specialization': cannot convert from 'std::string (__cdecl *)(const double)' to 'std::string (__cdecl *)(const double &)'
note: This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or a function-style cast
error C2973: 'convWrapper': invalid template argument 'std::string (__cdecl *)(const double)'
note: see declaration of 'ConvWrapper'
```

Based on where that last note links to, it seems like it's selected the wrong `ConvWrapper` then acting surprised when the `Callable` signature doesn't match.

What's weird is that [on Godbolt with the same compiler selected, the code is accepted](https://godbolt.org/z/KnTtK2).

Is there a configuration that could be affecting this? Is it me?

How can I fix it? Either with a configuration change or a code change?

Comment: Have you try removing "superfluous" `const` -> `std::string Foo(double val)` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yep. And it's not superfluous :( Well, not in the definition, anyway.

Comment: I get the code to compile with my MSVS 2017 (15.8.7) by changing conformance mode to `No` from `Yes (permissive-)` and using `/std:c++17` or `/std:latest`

Comment: @NathanOliver Ah interesting - `/permissive-` makes it break for me :) (I should have replicated all the flags on the Godbolt demo really)

Comment: It compiles for me, with just "/std:c++17", compiler version 19.16.27023.1. What is your compiler version (the version cl.exe prints)?

Comment: So either MSVS is too strict or gcc/clang are to laxed.  Not sure which way to go.  Would you like an answer saying `/permissive-` causes it to fail, turn it off?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah I think that'll be fine

Comment: @geza 19.14.26429.4

Comment: Is this simplification working for you [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/u7wwUb) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Looks like it. That's nice :)

Comment: @Jarod42 To be fair that'd be a good answer too

Comment: Misleading title (and error message), you're not specializing anything.

Comment: @ArneVogel Hmm - just "wrong template" then?

Comment: Here's a stripped down example: https://godbolt.org/z/5id7AK. Two funny things: 1) If you remove the template parameter name `C`, it will compile. 2) If you modify `Foo`'s parameter list to `const double &`, it still doesn't compile. It will try to use the other (therefore wrong again) overload.

Comment: @geza Haha, nice

Answer (score 5):

The compiler flag that causes the issue is the `/permissive-` conformance flag.  Removing it from your compiler command or changing it in Debug -> "name of project" properties -> C/C++ -> Language -> Conformance Mode to No will get it to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You might avoid the overloads, with c++17 by replacing `typename CallableType, CallableType Callable` by `auto Callable`.
Then MSVC doesn't need to convert between type.

```
template <typename InType, auto Callable, bool Strict>
Value ConvWrapperImpl(const Value& value)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<InType, Value>)
    {
        return Callable(value);
    }
    else
    {
        if (value.index() != 0)
        {
            const auto* ptr = std::get_if<InType>(&value);
            if (ptr)
                return Callable(*ptr);
        }

        return value;
    }
}

template <typename T1, auto Callable, bool Strict = false>
Value ConvWrapper(const Value& value, ReadStore&)
{
    return ConvWrapperImpl<T1, Callable, Strict>(value);
}
```

with similar usage (`ConvWrapper<double, &Foo>` instead of `ConvWrapper<double, std::string, &Foo>`):

```
int main()
{
    using namespace detail;

    ReadStore store;
    PrintConvType func = ConvWrapper<double, &Foo>;

    Value result = func(3.14159, store);
     std::cout << std::get<std::string>(result) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/u7wwUb)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, so I could keep conformance mode. Interestingly it would seem to confirm the observation that VS was picking the wrong overload. Maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your time!